# Algebraic number theory

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find the squarefree $D$ such that $D\equiv 2$ (mod $4$) and $\dfrac{2D+1+\sqrt{8D+1}}{2}$ is perfect square integer?  I need to find some $D$ (not necessary all).
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @PeterForeman No, it isn't. The natural number is called perfect square if it forms $k^2$ for some natural number. In this situation, $D=0$ is one solution, i need to find some number $D\ne 0$.

Comment: $D=0$ does not satisfy $D\equiv 2\bmod 4$.

Comment: oh. Sorry, i forget this condition @lhf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y^2=\dfrac{2D+1+\sqrt{8D+1}}{2}$. Then $D = \dfrac{2 y^2 \pm \sqrt{8 y^2 + 1}+ 1}{2}
$.

So, we need to solve the Pell equation $x^2-8y^2=1$, and then impose the restrictions on $D$.

Comment: For solution of the Pell equation, see https://oeis.org/A001541 and https://oeis.org/A001109.

Comment: I don't know why $D = \dfrac{2 y^2 \pm \sqrt{8 y^2 + 1}+ 1}{2}$. I try to tranform but the result i have is $D^2-D(2y^2-3)+y^4+y^2=0$.

Comment: I've asked [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cdfrac%7B2D%2B1%2B%5Csqrt%7B8D%2B1%7D%7D%7B2%7D++%3D+y%5E2,+solve+for+D), but it shouldn't be hard to do by hand. It reduces to a quadratic equation.

Comment: it's related to the existence of ideal lattice (respestedly principal ideal of ring of integer of numberfiled $Q(\sqrt{D})$ for $D$ satisfy above condition). My teacher 's check the existence of $D\le 10^6$.